# Moving to right 100% width fixed element

Tags: css, width, move, fixed

I have following code:

```
<div style="border:4px solid black;width:100%;height:100px;position:fixed;left:250px;">
out of bound :(
</div>
```

I want it not to cross the window. I need its right border to stay visible.

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/9SZAB/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `width` property and instead use `right: 0`:

```
div {
    border:4px solid black;
    height:100px;
    position:fixed;
    left:250px;
    right: 0;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9SZAB/2/

Why this works: `position: fixed` tells the element to have a fixed position relative to the viewport, so that the positioning properties `left`, `right`, `top`, and `bottom`, as well as `width` and `height` will position and size the element based on the size and boundaries of the viewport.

Previously you had `width: 100%`, which, combined with `position: fixed`, means that the element's width should be 100% of the viewport's width.  This width is not and should not be affected by any margins or positioning that you also set - the element will still have 100% of the viewport's width, no matter where it is.

But if the element has a width value of `auto` (which is default), then the positioning properties can be used to size it. Just as `left: 250px` means that the left side of the element should be 250px away from the viewport's left boundary, `right: 0` means that its right side should be 0 (px, em, parsecs - unit doesn't matter for a value of 0) away from the vp's right boundary. Resize the viewport and this state will still be true.

more info: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: wow thank you very much. It works, still cant figure out how, but its great. Will accept your answer as soon as possible (it writes 11 minutes remaining) THANK YOU VERY MUCH